# Writing text on a curve in pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

How do I write text like this over a curve like bezier, bspline etc. using pygame or python 3?

[image: text on curve]

Comment: Pygame does not have any support for this

Comment: if you don't need it dynamically drawn you can use the image you provided.  If you do want it dynamic then see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36118453/writing-text-on-a-curve-in-pygame#comment59877601_36118453).

Answer (score 1):

If you know the angles you want to display the text at, you could create images for each letter and then use pygame.transform.rotate on the letter to create a new, rotated image.

Answer (score 0):

Pygame text functions are limited to monochrome text rendering in a straightline, using the font's hinting.

Cairo (and PyCairo) however, offer heavy duty drawing and text rendering APIs - 
so you probably will have to learn how make your curved text in Cairo, and transfer the cairo image to a Pygame surface for your game.

There is a wiki page on how to transfer images between both here: http://pygame.org/wiki/CairoPygame  - I am not sure if Cairo's API alone contemplates curved text, but it can render SVG - so you can create your curved text in SVG, render it in cairo, and paste it in Pygame.